# When should "the weary blacksmith" conversation in act I take place?

Tags: diablo-iii, achievements

When should "the weary blacksmith" conversation with the blacksmith in Act I take place?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

At the beginning of "A Shattered Crown" you need to ignore Cain and talk directly to the Blacksmith. He will be right next to the Jeweler / Radek the Fence.